# Galleria how to delete

Tags: jquery, css, slideshow, galleria

I have classic galleria and I've hidden the thumbnails.

But I want to completely remove the thumbnails section not just hide it.

I want to put a few images directly under galleria .

And not have that empty space where the thumbnails are being hidden.

Here is a pic of what I mean:

http://img827.imageshack.us/img827/7246/overflowpic.jpg

I have tried the thumbnails false but I might be putting it in the wrong spot.

Comment: You'll need to show us some code...

Comment: the javascript and css is pages long would be to much to post here .i have been googling and banging my head on this for days

Comment: If it's not in the plugin options then search for how to remove an element in jquery. Find the element by inspecting the DOM using firebug or chrome's developer tools.

Comment: just curious have you ever used galleria ?

Comment: ok i got it in css i was able to shrink the hidden thumbnail container 


     .galleria-stage {
     position: absolute;
     top: 10px;
     bottom: 10px;
     left: 10px;
     right: 10px;
     overflow:hidden;
      }

i hope this helps someone in the future , i spent for ever going in circles